# sbt is not including the main class in the manifest after assembly

Tags: scala, sbt

I am using `sbt 1.2.8` with assembly plugin. This is my sbt file:

```
name := "my-project"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ... some dependency ...
)

mainClass in (Compile, assembly) := Some("some.package.MyMainClass")

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

After I run the command `sbt assembly` configured in `assembly.sbt` with:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.7")
```

I get the following content from the extracted file:

```
scala-2.11 $ cat META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: my-project
Implementation-Version: 0.1
Specification-Vendor: default
Specification-Title: my-project
Implementation-Vendor-Id: default
Specification-Version: 0.1
Implementation-Vendor: default
```

but I cannot see where my main class is specified. Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

It works for me. The only change I did is rename assembly.sbt to plugins.sbt. Try it out.

Comment: Will be great to look at project structure. Just to double check, the MANIFEST.MF you have extracted from jar produced by `sbt assembly`, right?

Comment: the file path is: `my-project/src/main/scala/some/package/MyMainClass.scala`

Comment: It works for me as well. `assembly` created `so-57212841-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` and if I unzip it and do `cat META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` I see the `Main-Class` correctly set

Comment: So that problem was that you checked wrong MANIFEST.MF?